# Composer Installer warning no such host is known, failed to open stream

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I am trying to install composer on windows 10 I am getting the following error, and when I am trying to enter `composer -v` through cmd I am getting error also, means composer not installed in my computer, The error or warning I am getting is this

> "The "https://getcomposer.org/versions" file could not be downloaded: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known.
> failed to open stream: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known.
> The "https://getcomposer.org/download/1.10.10/composer.phar.sig" file could not be downloaded: failed to open stream: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

[image]

Please help some one.

Answer (score 0):

You can try again but everything is working now. Maybe there is some network issue at your end (firewall, proxy, etc).

Download composer.phar instead https://getcomposer.org/composer-stable.phar

and then you can run "php composer-stable.phar".